# The website resizes when the left property is changed

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a mobile navigation system implemented to my website, and it works perfectly on computers, however when I test the website on mobile devices it works as well however the website changes it size when the element is moved from `left: -240px;` to `left: 0;`

### My question

Why is the website changing it's size and how to fix this issue?

---

Here is my code:

The meta tag:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initital-scale=1.0" />
```

The body tag:

```
<body class="mobile-nav-off"></body>
```

The mobile navigation:

```
<header id="main-template-header-mobile">
  <div id="main-template-navigation-mobile-container" class="mobile-navigation-right">
    <ul id="main-template-navigation-mobile">
      <li id="logo"><img src="assets/img/websiteLogo.png" /></li>
      <li class="current"><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>

  <div id="main-template-mobile-header">
    <a id="main-template-mobile-expander" href="#"><i class="fa fa-bars fa-lg"></i></a>
  </div>
</header>
```

The JavaScript

```
$menuLeft = $('#main-template-navigation-mobile-container');
    $nav_list = $('#main-template-mobile-expander');

    $nav_list.click(function() {
        $('.mobile-nav-off').toggleClass('mobile-nav-on');
        $menuLeft.toggleClass('mobile-navigation-right-push');
    });
```

And the CSS:

```
#main-template-header-mobile {
    display: none;
    z-index: 3000;
}

#main-template-navigation-mobile-container {
    position: fixed;
    width: 240px;
    height: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.mobile-navigation-right {
    left: -240px;
}

.mobile-navigation-right-push {
    left: 0;
}

.mobile-nav-off {
    position: relative;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    left: 0;
}

.mobile-nav-on {
    left: 240px;
}
```

Comment: what is your question?

Comment: @charlietfl Why the website is resizing?

Comment: That's a pretty vague question. Use your browsers' debug tools (F12 or the Firefox Firebug extension), and you'll be able to see which _specific element_ is causing the problem. PS: Chrome and Safari, are capable of remote debugging.

Comment: Try keep the `overflow-x: hidden;` in `.mobile-nav-on`. Maybe the *body* is going outside the screen, increasing the website size.

Comment: @RafaelAlmeida Hi, unfortunately it's not working

Comment: Can you fiddle it? https://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: @RafaelAlmeida I tried to make a fiddle, but for some reason it won't work, and I cannot add meta tag in there